# Grouping using LINQ - returning zero records

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm currently learning about LINQ amongst other things, but am having trouble grouping.  I simply want to display unique values within the combobox for TxtProductFamily.  I am getting zero entries in the dropdown:

```
var sel = (from o in db.r2_machine group o by o.product_family).ToList();
TxtProductFamily.ItemsSource = sel;
```

Comment: could you help me with what I should put.  Thank you.

Comment: When you debug, check to see if "sel" has results in it.  If it does not, troubleshoot why the query is returning zero results.  However, if it does have results in it, troubleshoot why the results are not being turned into dropdown values by the combo box control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to do like this:

```
var sel = (from o in db.r2_machine 
           group o by o.product_family into g
           select g.Key).ToList();
TxtProductFamily.ItemsSource = sel;
```

Comment: if data is there it should work can you show some data

Comment: @AndyDB "ignore that last bit" what you mean?

Comment: you can delete that comment..:)

Answer (score 1):

You are not selecting any data after grouping. Use `Select` method.

```
  var sel = (from o in db.r2_machine 
             group o by o.product_family into g 
             select g.Key).ToList();

  TxtProductFamily.ItemsSource = sel;
```

Comment: Out of interest, why did you call `Select` using the lambda syntax rather than the query syntax the rest of the query uses?

Answer (score 1):

You must select something to get output

```
var outPut= (from o in db.r2_machine 
           group o by o.product_family into g
           select g).ToList();
TxtProductFamily.ItemsSource = outPut;
```